# Set fixed height in Flexbox/CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've just started playing around with HTML/CSS/Javascript and have a question. I've been through the MDN pages on Flexbox but I don't see how to set a fixed layout with it. Here is what I mean:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="left"> Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed.
      PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock. </div>
    <div class="right"> Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"> Down</div>
</div>
```

I have a "wrapper" div(specified as flex) that is meant to hold the "top" div and the "bottom" div. I would like the "top" div to occupy 70% of my page irrespective of the size of the display. I would also like the "bottom" div to occupy the bottom 30% of my page, irrespective of the size of the display. I've seen some code on MDN that uses floats to achieve this, but I was wondering how to do this in flexbox? Here is what I have so far in my CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  min-height: 70% /*doesn't work*/
}

.top{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.left {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  width: 48%;
  float: right;
}

.bottom {
  min-height: 30%
}
```

If I've missed some important points in Flexbox or if someone can suggest more resources that I can read to learn this better, I'd be grateful!

Here is a jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wtbx6s77/24/)!

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/z2dtwtbo/)?

Comment: @insertusernamehere: Yup, thanks for that! I'm embarrassed now that I see that I should've put the min-height in the "top" selector

Answer (score 0):

The wrapper needs to take up the entire viewport -- then inside of it, the top needs to be told it is 70% and bottom 30% using flex-basis.

There is [short-hand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to combine flex-basis, flex-grow and flex-shrink as just 'flex'; however, here is my solution without shorthand so you can see each css statement:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%
}

.top{
  flex-basis: 70%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.bottom {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

You did not say what left/right do; however, I'm assuming you just want a nested flexbox in there. If so, add this to the .top class

```
.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left,
.right {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```